# Specify SameSite=None and Secure in ASP .Net Core MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, iframe, asp.net-core-mvc, samesite

I am creating a web application using ASP .NET Core MVC (.NET 5.0 and MVC5).
In one of the web page, have an iframe which needs to be loaded with a tableau view.
Trusted Authentication to tableau server is setup and also getting the token.
But the tableau view (or any other website) is not loading in an iframe.

I am getting this error:
***Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute***

When I was researching on this issue, I understood we need to set the cookie property as  SameSite=None and Secure.
Please help me out on where to set the sameSite attribute to none and secure.

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Sanjay did you get the solution on how to set the samesite to none and secure to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by setting cookies SameSite attribute as None from Tableau Server end.

I followed the steps given in this article:

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/signing-into-tableau-server-and-loading-embedded-views-fails-on-safari-12-after-upgrading-tableau-server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will solve your problem, but here's the config for sending cookie cross-site and secure:

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "your-cookie";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // to bypass consent check
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Only send cookie through HTTP
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
```

In `Configure`, add `app.UseAuthentication()` after `app.UseRouting()`.

Note that Asp.net Core only allows `SameSiteMode.None` when Cookie Policy is `CookieSecurePolicy.Always`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Tried this but it is not working. Still seeing the same property for the cookie and the iframe is not loading.